# How to automate the transfer of files between Linux servers using SCP?

Tags: linux

I'm writing a script to automatically transfer files between two different Linux servers. Every time I use the SCP command, it requires me to input a password. Is there anyway around this for an automated process?

Comment: Public key authentication. Also, consider using rsync.

Answer (score 1):

As Lev Levitsky commented, SSH Public Key Authentication is what you need in order to get around being prompted for a password every time you use scp to copy a file.  See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/ for an excellent step-by-step guide on how to setup SSH Public Key Authentication.